# Postgresql Query where parent's parent ID equals id

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following table relation structure. *(I'm pretty new to SQL so go easy on me)* Also, I'm using Postgresql, which idk if that changes anything.

```
Users -> Services -> Sessions -> Visits
```

Basically, users have multiple services, services have multiple sessions and sessions have multiple visits.

I'm trying to build a COUNT query to count all the visits a service has in a time period. My problem is that this requires querying the visit's session's service ID.

So far I've come up with the following query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM visits
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN now()::timestamp - (interval '30days') AND now()::timestamp)
AND (session.service = 'NDBKaG3a68tAOgHS');
```

and am getting the following error when trying to run that:

```sql
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "session"
LINE 4: AND (session.service = 'NDBKaG3a68tAOgHS')
```

My attempt to query the session's service is the line `AND (session.service = 'NDBKaG3a68tAOgHS');` How should I query this parent's parent relationship?

Comment: You simply need to join to the parent table. It should be something like `FROM visits inner join sessions on visits.session = sessions.id` and the `WHERE` clause then needs sessions not session. I am assuming that table names are plurals, primary keys are called id and foreign keys are singular name of the parent table.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock your assumptions are corrent, I'll try your suggestion right now

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Worked like a charm! Do you wan to post a real answer and I'll mark it as the accepted one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to join to the parent table. It should be something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM visits INNER JOIN sessions on visits.session = sessions.id
WHERE (visits.created_at BETWEEN now()::timestamp - (interval '30days') AND now()::timestamp)
AND (sessions.service = 'NDBKaG3a68tAOgHS');
```

I am assuming that table names are plurals, primary keys are called id and foreign keys are singular name of the parent table.

Note that this is standard `SQL` syntax, so this solution is not peculiar to PostgreSQL, but would apply to other DBs as well.